# Div with overflow hidden, no work on chat invite image script

Tags: css, css-float

Please Help me! I have a problem.

please view the image: http://s15.postimg.org/wyb1fs7kr/duvida.png

I have a div with a chat icon status, but this same script that calls the icon status, also calls the image of chat invitation, the image of chat invitation is higher, it should appear centered on the screen, but does not appear because it is inside the div with overflow: hidden and float: right

As it is currently the chat invitation will not appear to the visitor because the image is larger than the div and the div has overflow hidden

```
#topo05_aten_space .boxaten {
    width: 331px;
    height: 87px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #cd420e; 
}

#topo05_aten_space .boxaten:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    border-top: 87px solid #cd420e; 
    border-right: 87px solid #cd420e; 
    width: 0;
}


#topo05_aten_space .iconaten{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    width: 267px;
    height: 87px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 6;
}

<div id="topo05_aten_space">
    <div class="boxaten">
    </div>
    <div class="iconaten">
        <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.domain.com.br/atendimento/js/status_image.php?base_url=http://www.domain.com.br/atendimento&l=admin&x=1&deptid=6&"><a href="/atendimento/setup/code.php"></a></script>
    </div></div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have a lot of css that is not necessary here. Like `position: absolute;` but you don't have a wrapper that has relative. Also `float: right;` won't do much with a absolute position on the div. Why not solve it without absolute?

Comment: http://s15.postimg.org/wyb1fs7kr/duvida.png   the problem is not with the positioning, but with the image of chat invitation which is a floating image displayed by a javascript that should appear in the center of the screen, but as javascript is inside this div does not appear because she has hidden overflow. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: please view the image: http://s15.postimg.org/wyb1fs7kr/duvida.png

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
#topo05_aten_space{
    position:absolute;
}
```

and removing 'right:0;' from '#topo05_aten_space .iconaten'

Comment: the problem is not with the positioning, but with the image of chat invitation which is a floating image displayed by a javascript that should appear in the center of the screen, but as javascript is inside this div does not appear because she has hidden overflow. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: so, did i understand correctly that you need to show that invitation to chat on top of everything, but since the parent div has overflow:hidden it cuts the invitation image? can you put that invitation image in the parent of that div? for example as the first element in <body>? and move it to the correct location using position:absolute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. You wrap the area, move out the chat of the overflow div. Position it like you need. I gave you a hint on the style you can use below, it's just a start.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="topo05_aten_space">
        <div class="boxaten">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="iconaten">
        <!--script-->
    </div>
</div>



.container {
   position: relative;
}

.iconaten {
   position: absolute;
   top: /* somevalue */
   left: /* somevalue */
}
```